# Variance of ratio of two independent binomial random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, variance, binomial-distribution, ratio

How can I compute

$$\text{Var}\left[\frac{a+X}{b+Y}\right]$$

for $a, b > 0$, $X\sim Bin(n,p)$, and $Y \sim Bin(m,p)$ and $X,Y$ independent? I know that adding some constant to a binomially distributed variable is no longer binomial, which is why the above becomes troublesome to evaluate analytically.

Some transformation that facilitates the approximation given in [Katz et al. (1978)](https://doi.org/10.2307/2530610) is also fine for me. Invoking the paper referenced would allow stating that for $X$ and $Y$ as given above (i.e., without the non-negative constants $a$ and $b$), then
$$\log{\frac{X/n}{Y/m}} \overset{\text{approx}}{\sim} \mathcal{N}\left(0,\frac{m+n}{nm}\right).$$

I feel like the transformation is painfully obvious, but I'm just not seeing it.

Answer (score 1):

By independence, $$\begin{align}\text{Var}\left[\frac{a+X}{b+Y}\right]&=E\left[\frac{a+X}{b+Y}\right]^2-\left(E\left[\frac{a+X}{b+Y}\right]\right)^2\\
&=E\left[a+X\right]^2E\left[b+Y\right]^{-2}-\left(E\left[a+X\right]\right)^2\left(E\left[b+Y\right]^{-1}\right)^{2}\end{align}.$$

Can you take it from here?